# Create a matrix/table from a LEFT JOIN in SQL

Tags: mysql, join, matrix, left-join

I'd like to know a good solution for converting a LEFT JOIN into a table/matrix.

For example, given this schema:

```
objects
   id (integer)
   name (string)

attributes
   id (integer)
   object_id (integer)
   name (string)
   value (string)
```

And these values:

```
1,ball
2,box

1,1,colour,red
2,1,shape,sphere
3,1,material,rubber
4,2,colour,brown
5,2,shape,cube
```

I'd like to get this:

```
object_id | object_name | colour | shape  | material

1         | ball        | red    | sphere | rubber
2         | box         | brown  | cube   | NULL
```

Ideally this would be with an unknown number of attributes for each object, and be for MySQL without using stored procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing with [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system)s is that their purpose is to store and present what you already have. Creating columns dynamically was never intended.

This is a case that should be handled on the client that is to present the data.

With disregard to how RDBMSs are supposed to be used, you still won't find an easy way to do this. Especially not if you want the column list to be dynamic. You can build a dynamic SQL query and execute that, but there's no way to write a standard SQL query and get that result (since you always specify all columns explicitly, bar using `*`, but that can't be used to your advantage in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it without using dynamical queries in `SQL`.

Any set `SQL` deals with assumes a fixed number of columns, with fixed names.

Otherwise it would lead to many things `SQL` is just not designed to deal with.

Like, imagine a view created on the query you asking for (were it possible):

```
SELECT  object_id, colour
FROM    myquery
```

Whether this view compiles or not would depend on the results of the query and this would give you runtime errors (which are hard to handle) instead of mere empty resultset (which is easy to handle).

You are basically talking about the results presentation here, and these things are usially done on the client side.

If you have `attribute_names` table which contains all possible names of your attributes, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT  o.name, an.name, a.value
FROM    objects o
CROSS JOIN
        attribute_names an
LEFT JOIN
        attributes a
ON      a.object = o.id
        AND a.name = an.name
```

, which will contain all possible `object_id / attribute_name` pairs with corresponding values, and you can use it on client side to fill a matrix more easily.

Answer (score 0):

This would solve your problem assuming the result table is called merged, although the schema you have I'd say was better.

```
insert into merged (object_id, object_name) select id, name from objects;
update merged m inner join attributes a on a.object_id = m.object_id and a.name = 'colour' set m.colour = a.value;
update merged m inner join attributes a on a.object_id = m.object_id and a.name = 'material' set m.material = a.value;
update merged m inner join attributes a on a.object_id = m.object_id and a.name = 'shape' set m.shape = a.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm this is possible your just missing 2 logical steps to make this happen.

What you need is an AttributeTypes table and an AttributeValues table.

```
objects
   id (integer)
   name (string)

attribute_types
   id (integer)
   name (string)
   description (string)
   enabled (bit)

attribute_values
   id (integer)
   attribute_type_id (integer)
   value (string)
   enabled (bit)

attributes
   id (integer)
   object_id (integer)
   attribute_type_id (integer)
   attribute_value_id (integer)
```

So an object can have attributes, these attributes are specified by an attribute_type_id and attribute_value_id.

This then allows you to have an object with multiple attributes..

eg

```
object 
-> 1, ball

attribute_types
-> 10, Colour, null, enabled
-> 20, Shape, null, enabled
-> 30, Material, null, enabled

attribute_values 
-> 100, 10, blue, enabled
-> 200, 10, red, enabled
-> 300, 10, green, enabled

-> 400, 20, round, enabled
-> 500, 20, square, enabled
-> 600, 20, triangle, enabled
```

So an attribute would look like:

```
attributes
-> 1000, 1, 10, 100 // this item has a color and it is blue
-> 1001, 1, 20, 400 // this item has a shape and it is round
-> 1002, 1, 10, 200 // this item has a color and it is red
```

So now objects can have multiple attributes which specify their values in different tables. Now the important question how do you query this? You may have to split the query into multiple parts depending how strong your sql is.

```
@attribute_type_id = select Id from attribute_types where name = 'Color' // 10

select * from objects 
inner join attributes on objects.id = attributes.object_id
inner join attribute_values on objects.attribute_value_id = attribute_values.id
where attribute_type_id = @attribute_type_id
and attribute_values.value= 'blue'
```

And there you have it you should bring back every object that has the attribute_type of Color and the attribute_value of blue.

My Sql isn't that strong but you should be able to do more than one clause if you want to search for multiple attributes at a time. In my mind attribute_type_id in attributes table isn't joined onto the attribute_type table, but it can be to facilitate doing the query in 1 hit, performance wise though I'de have it so it would speed up the queries by not having to join a table but the difference might be negligible depending on how big everything gets.

Note: I normally work with msssql and not mysql so if the database types don't match up that's why.